# get value from multiple checkbox's selected and append into jtextarea

Tags: java, checkbox, textarea

My current code will only append the last checkbox selected. I need to get all values from selected checkbox and append into jtextarea to later be printed. Maybe an array but not sure how to append an array. Thanks for any help!

EDIT: I solved this! Instead of taking the values to the append method, I took the append method to the values to get my desired output.I posted updated code.

```
        private void jBtnRecieptActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                            
    //declare local variables
    String item = null;
    int quanity = 0;
    double priceEa = 0;
    double total = 0;

    if (jCTiteliestGolfBall.isSelected()) {
        quanity = Integer.parseInt(jQty1.getText());
        item = jCTiteliestGolfBall.getActionCommand();
        priceEa = 1.50;
        total = (priceEa * quanity);
    }
    if (jCTiteliestGolfClubs.isSelected()) {
        quanity = Integer.parseInt(jQty2.getText());
        item = jCTiteliestGolfClubs.getActionCommand();
        priceEa = 150.00;
        total = (priceEa * quanity); 
    }
    if (jCGregNormanGolfShirt.isSelected()) {
        quanity = Integer.parseInt(jQty3.getText());
        item = jCGregNormanGolfShirt.getActionCommand();
        priceEa = 15.00;
        total = (priceEa * quanity);
    }
    if (jCGregNormanGolfHat.isSelected()) {
        quanity = Integer.parseInt(jQty4.getText());
        item = jCGregNormanGolfHat.getActionCommand();
        priceEa = 10.00;
        total = (priceEa * quanity);
    }
    if (jCGolfGlove.isSelected()) {
        quanity = Integer.parseInt(jQty5.getText());
        item = jCGolfGlove.getActionCommand();
        priceEa = 2.00;
        total = (priceEa * quanity);
    }
    if (jCGolfTees.isSelected()) {
        quanity = Integer.parseInt(jQty6.getText());
        item = jCGolfTees.getActionCommand();
        priceEa = .50;
        total = (priceEa * quanity);
    }
    DateTimeFormatter dtf = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy/MM/dd   HH:mm:ss");
    LocalDateTime now = LocalDateTime.now();
    date = (dtf.format(now));


    jTextAreaReciept.append("\tFolly Beach Golf:\n" + item + "   " + quanity + "  @  " 
            +   String.format("%.2f", priceEa) + "  =   " + String.format("%.2f", total) 
            + "\nSubtotal: " + jTextFieldCostofItems.getText()
            + "\nTax: " + jTextFieldTax.getText() 
            + "\nTotal: " + jTextFieldTotal.getText()
            + "\n\nDate/Time:  " + date + "\n\n\tThank you for your business");
```

UPDATED:
        private void jBtnRecieptActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
        //declare local variables
        String item ="";
        int quanity = 0;
        double priceEa = 0;
        double total = 0;

```
    jTextAreaReciept.append("\tFolly Beach Golf:\n");

    if (jCTiteliestGolfBall.isSelected()) {
        quanity = Integer.parseInt(jQty1.getText());
        item = jCTiteliestGolfBall.getActionCommand();
        priceEa = 1.50;
        total = (priceEa * quanity);
        jTextAreaReciept.append("\n" + item + "   " + quanity + "  @  " 
            +   String.format("%.2f", priceEa) + "  =   " + String.format("%.2f", total)); 
    }
    if (jCTiteliestGolfClubs.isSelected()) {
        quanity = Integer.parseInt(jQty2.getText());
        item = jCTiteliestGolfClubs.getActionCommand();
        priceEa = 150.00;
        total = (priceEa * quanity);
        jTextAreaReciept.append("\n" + item + "   " + quanity + "  @  " 
            +   String.format("%.2f", priceEa) + "  =   " + String.format("%.2f", total));
    }
    if (jCGregNormanGolfShirt.isSelected()) {
        quanity = Integer.parseInt(jQty3.getText());
        item = jCGregNormanGolfShirt.getActionCommand();
        priceEa = 15.00;
        total = (priceEa * quanity);
        jTextAreaReciept.append("\n" + item + "   " + quanity + "  @  " 
            +   String.format("%.2f", priceEa) + "  =   " + String.format("%.2f", total));
    }
    if (jCGregNormanGolfHat.isSelected()) {
        quanity = Integer.parseInt(jQty4.getText());
        item = jCGregNormanGolfHat.getActionCommand();
        priceEa = 10.00;
        total = (priceEa * quanity);
        jTextAreaReciept.append("\n" + item + "   " + quanity + "  @  " 
            +   String.format("%.2f", priceEa) + "  =   " + String.format("%.2f", total));
    }
    if (jCGolfGlove.isSelected()) {
        quanity = Integer.parseInt(jQty5.getText());
        item = jCGolfGlove.getActionCommand();
        priceEa = 2.00;
        total = (priceEa * quanity);
        jTextAreaReciept.append("\n" + item + "   " + quanity + "  @  " 
            +   String.format("%.2f", priceEa) + "  =   " + String.format("%.2f", total));
    }
    if (jCGolfTees.isSelected()) {
        quanity = Integer.parseInt(jQty6.getText());
        item = jCGolfTees.getActionCommand();
        priceEa = .50;
        total = (priceEa * quanity);
        jTextAreaReciept.append("\n" + item + "   " + quanity + "  @  " 
            +   String.format("%.2f", priceEa) + "  =   " + String.format("%.2f", total));
    }
    DateTimeFormatter dtf = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy/MM/dd   HH:mm:ss");
    LocalDateTime now = LocalDateTime.now();
    date = (dtf.format(now));


    jTextAreaReciept.append("\n\nSubtotal: " + jTextFieldCostofItems.getText()
            + "\nTax: " + jTextFieldTax.getText() 
            + "\nTotal: " + jTextFieldTotal.getText()
            + "\n\nDate/Time:  " + date + "\n\n\tThank you for your business");
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code :

```
private void jBtnRecieptActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                            
    //declare local variables
    String item = "";
    int quanity = 0;
    double priceEa = 0;
    double total = 0;

    if (jCTiteliestGolfBall.isSelected()) {
        quanity += Integer.parseInt(jQty1.getText());
        item += jCTiteliestGolfBall.getActionCommand();
        priceEa += 1.50;
        total += (priceEa * quanity);
    }
    if (jCTiteliestGolfClubs.isSelected()) {
        quanity += Integer.parseInt(jQty2.getText());
        item += jCTiteliestGolfClubs.getActionCommand();
        priceEa += 150.00;
        total += (priceEa * quanity); 
    }
    if (jCGregNormanGolfShirt.isSelected()) {
        quanity += Integer.parseInt(jQty3.getText());
        item += jCGregNormanGolfShirt.getActionCommand();
        priceEa += 15.00;
        total += (priceEa * quanity);
    }
    if (jCGregNormanGolfHat.isSelected()) {
        quanity += Integer.parseInt(jQty4.getText());
        item += jCGregNormanGolfHat.getActionCommand();
        priceEa += 10.00;
        total += (priceEa * quanity);
    }
    if (jCGolfGlove.isSelected()) {
        quanity += Integer.parseInt(jQty5.getText());
        item += jCGolfGlove.getActionCommand();
        priceEa += 2.00;
        total += (priceEa * quanity);
    }
    if (jCGolfTees.isSelected()) {
        quanity += Integer.parseInt(jQty6.getText());
        item += jCGolfTees.getActionCommand();
        priceEa += .50;
        total += (priceEa * quanity);
    }
    DateTimeFormatter dtf = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy/MM/dd   HH:mm:ss");
    LocalDateTime now = LocalDateTime.now();
    date = (dtf.format(now));


    jTextAreaReciept.append("\tFolly Beach Golf:\n" + item + "   " + quanity + "  @  " 
            +   String.format("%.2f", priceEa) + "  =   " + String.format("%.2f", total) 
            + "\nSubtotal: " + jTextFieldCostofItems.getText()
            + "\nTax: " + jTextFieldTax.getText() 
            + "\nTotal: " + jTextFieldTotal.getText()
            + "\n\nDate/Time:  " + date + "\n\n\tThank you for your business");
```